# Phonegap JAVA_HOME variable error when using "run android"

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, sdk

Node.js keeps telling me JAVA_HOME isn't pointing to the SDK but I'm sure it is.

Here's an image of the error and my variable setup.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a352.jpg

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave the `\bin` folder off of java home, so just `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20` should suffice.

If using the android build tools you will need the `tools` and `platform-tools` directory added to `PATH`.

```
##update ANDROID_SDK with your local installation path
ANDROID_SDK="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk"
PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_SDK%\tools
```

You can verify the correct location of JAVA_HOME in the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html)

Comment: wow, that did the trick small errors never cease to amaze me, thanks a lot!